# Erro com o Webdriver no Python3.5 AttributeError: can't set attribute

Tags: python, scrapy, selenium-webdriver

Estou precisando baixar o conteúdo de um site. Fiz um código em python 3.5. Quando eu o rodo apenas para uma única pagina o código funciona muito bem porém quando eu o coloco em um loop ou função ele dá erro.

O código como função é o seguinte:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import html2text


def getPEP(strg):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.page_source = driver.get(strg)
    html = driver.page_source
    driver.close()
    text=html2text.html2text(html)
    return(text);

def salva():
    peps = open('PEP.txt', 'r')
    lines = tuple(peps)
    peps.close()
    for i in range(1):
        strg=lines[i].replace('\n','') 
        print(strg + '\n')
        str(strg)
        getPEP(strg)
        start = '#  '
        end = ', \n\n[ ![Join us on'
        cleaned=(text.split(start))[1].split(end)[0]
        file = open(str(i)+'.txt', 'w')
        file.write(cleaned.replace(' ** ','').replace('**',''))
        file.close()
        print('arquivo ' + str(i) + 'gravado com sucesso' )
    return;

salva()
```

Quando eu coloco apenas na linha de comando como a seguinte:

```
>>> strg='http://www.mtsamples.com/site/pages/sample.asp?type=3-Allergy%20/%20Immunology&sample=386-Allergic%20Rhinitis, Allergic Rhinitis'
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.page_source = driver.get(strg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
>>> html = driver.page_source
>>> driver.close()
>>> text=html2text.html2text(html)
```

Por mais que retorne esse erro eu ainda consigo recuperar o texto do site. 
agora quando eu coloco como função:

```
>>> def getPEP(strg):
...     driver = webdriver.Firefox()
...     driver.page_source = driver.get(strg)
...     html = driver.page_source
...     driver.close()
...     text=html2text.html2text(html)
...     return(text);
... 
>>> text=getPEP()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: getPEP() missing 1 required positional argument: 'strg'
```

Então o programa para no erro e não retorna o texto que eu preciso! Alguém pode me ajudar?

---

A fucao getPEP() funcionou, obrigada! Agora o meu código está assim:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import html2text



# driver.page_source = driver.get())#
def getPEP(strg):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(strg)
    html = driver.page_source
    driver.close()
    text=html2text.html2text(html)
    return(text);

def salva(arqv):
    peps = open(arqv, 'r')
    lines = tuple(peps)
    peps.close()
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        strg=lines[i].replace('\n','') 
        text=getPEP(strg)
        start = '#  '
        end = ', \n\n[ ![Join us on'
        cleaned=(text.split(start))[1].split(end)[0]
        file = open(str(i)+'.txt', 'w')
        file.write(cleaned.replace(' ** ','').replace('**',''))
        file.close()
        print('arquivo ' + str(i) + 'gravado com sucesso' )
    return;

getPEP('PEP.txt')
```

A função getPEP(strg) esta funcionando perfeitamente, obrigada! 
Porám quando chamo a função `salva(arqv)` que era para ler as urls que eu quero baixar, coletar o texto que eu quero salvar por meio da função `getPEP(strg)` e gravar em um arquivo, está dando o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawlerPEP.py", line 35, in <module>
    getPEP('PEP.txt')
  File "crawlerPEP.py", line 10, in getPEP
    driver.get(strg)
  File "/home/angelica/Documents/PyEnv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 248, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/home/angelica/Documents/PyEnv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/angelica/Documents/PyEnv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Target URL PEP.txt is not well-formed.
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.get (file:///tmp/tmpiag201lm/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10636)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpiag201lm/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpiag201lm/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpiag201lm/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.page_source = driver.get(strg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

O erro indica que não foi possível definir um atributo, [`page_source`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source) é usado para retornar o conteúdo da página, você não pode sobrescrevê-lo. Coloque o resultado em uma variável:

```
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.get(strg)
>>> conteudo = driver.page_source
```

O segundo erro:

```
>>> text=getPEP()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: getPEP() missing 1 required positional argument: 'strg'
```

A função `getPEP` espera um argumento, que neste caso é a URL  que você quer obter o conteúdo. Passe a URL para a função:

```
>>> strg = 'http://www.mtsamples.com/site/pages/......'
>>> text = getPEP(strg)
```

A função `getPEP` deve ficar assim:

```
>>> def getPEP(strg):
...     driver = webdriver.Firefox()
...     driver.get(strg)
...     html = driver.page_source
...     driver.close()
...     text = html2text.html2text(html)
...     return (text)
```

Comment: Obrigada! Agora esta apresentando outro erro coloquei na pergunta acima poderia me ajudar novamente?

Comment: @user2535338 Você está passando o nome do arquivo para `getPEP` (ele pede uma URL), não era para usar a função `salva`? assim: `salva('PEP.txt')`.

Comment: Sao varias URLs que estao nesse arquivo 'PEP.txt'

Comment: @user2535338 Na função `salva` você chama `getPEP` para cada linha (URL) presente no arquivo e salva o resultado num novo arquivo tendo como nome o número da linha.